# ORACLE SCRIPT SQL

Tags: oracle, scripting

I need to Schedule a script That Will drop the last restore point created.

the restore point is created with this command :

> export DATEXP=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`
>   cd /save/PROD/restorePoints
>   sqlplus "/as sysdba" << eof >> createRestorePoint.log
>   create restore point RESP_$DATEXP GUARANTEE FLASHBACK DATABASE;

And now,I need to drop this restore point, without droping the others :

> DROP RESTORE POINT *********;

could you help please ?

The Idea is to launch script which gonna drop the latest restore point.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you connect to the target db, query sys.v$restore_point for the NAME that matches the max(TIME) to find the most recently created restore point then use execute immediate to run the drop.

Comment: Yes I do : SELECT NAME FROM V$RESTORE_POINT WHERE GUARANTEE_FLASHBACK_DATABASE='YES';

NAME  
-------------------
RESP_201901251710

Comment: I need the entire script please to drop the latest one please

Comment: user6819529, you should try writing the script yourself.  Just write the SELECT which only returns one row then open the PL/SQL manual to figure out how to pass the target value into an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.